# User friendships Nesting logic in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am trying to finish my forum application. I want arrange user Friendships. I am using devise as authentication system. I want some suggestions. 
Shall i nest the resources in User and Friendships. This is the way Railscasts used:

```
devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show] 
  resources :friendships, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

This is how i used:

```
devise_for :users

      resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do
      resources :friendships, only: [:create, :destroy]
      end
```

My real problem is that . I want to use friendships in a way that , signed_in user can check the users list , and add a friend if he is not in the friendslist. Now i can add a friend multiple times. And also ,user can add himself as a friend.

How can i fix this links with `if/else` statements:

showing a user profile  works:

```
<section>
      <h1>
        <%= @user.username %>
      </h1>

            <%= link_to "Arkadaşlarıma Ekle", friendships_path(:friend_id => @user), :method => :post,class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

      </section>
```

and herei I cant find the way to show the friend's profile. :

```
<%  for friendship in @friendships %> 
<%= link_to friendship.friend.username, '#' %>
(<%= link_to 'Sil', friendship, :method => :delete %>)
<% end %>
```

..
rake routes:

I can understand that , I have to use correct if/elses but i am lost in nesting my resources and routing. . Thanks for explanations..

These are my edits:
In my users_controller:

```
def user_is_friend?(other_user)
 current_user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(other_user.id) 
end

<% unless user_is_friend?(@user) %>
  <%= button_to "Add friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post %>
<% end %>
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you, in your user index view, when you are looping with a variable user (`for @users do |user|)` to add first a condition:

```
<% unless current_user == user %>
```

--> this will allow you to process all users except the current_user (i.e. yourself)

Then, you can define this:

```
<% user_is_friend = current_user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(user.id) %>
```

This will be TRUE if the user is already in your friend's list

And then, a last piece:

```
<% if !user_is_friend %>
  <%= button_to "Add friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The POST corresponds to a create action in your friendship controller. As you assign the user to ':friend_id', you can build the corresponding friendship by doing: '@friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])'

Comment: There is not any problem with adding friends. The only problem is with the added friends conditions. I need a method definition for it.

Comment: Well, if I read again your question, it looks like it is now answered. If it's not the case, I guess you should rephrase it.